# How to map function symbol to address range

Tags: c, linux

What is the proper way to determine the address range for a function symbol (string)?
I'll be working with statically-linked, non-stripped C programs on Linux.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
char* func_name = get_string_from_user();
printf("start address: %p \n", get_addr_range(func_name).start);
printf("end address: %p \n", get_addr_range(func_name).end);
```

Where the start address should be the actual address of the function as layed out currently in memory.
I think gdb and objdump perform similar actions, so it should be possible, right?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably doable with an object file or dll, but I suspect that information is lost when a process is loaded into memory. If the question is instead, "how can I find the range of this function in this object file", that's probably reasonably easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the [BFD](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/bfd/index.html) library provided with binutils (with objdump and and the rest). I have used it once briefly and it's not exactly trivial as far as I remember.

There are some usage examples out there (search for "using libbfd" or something like that).
I'd recommend reading the binutils utilities source code also.

There is also elfutils which comes with ELF and DWARF routines. Haven't used that one though and documentation looks sparse.

Comment: This seems like the strongest approach to me. The linker (or some of the tools that interact with object files) must know.

Comment: I was able to get the start address from BFD. I will keep looking. I'll also investigate elfutils. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not generally possible to get the entire range of a function.

At best, you can get the starting address.  Here is an example, it is NOT portable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("fputs = %p\n", (void *)fputs);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why this is not possible is because in general, the only information the linker uses about each object, whether function or data, is its address and its name (and a few bits of other data).  The linker just doesn't care about how big something is.

Now, you *can* find out how big a function is by examining the debugging data, if the debugging data is present for the given function.  There are libraries you can use to parse the data, as it can be somewhat complicated.  Here's a link to some information about DWARF, if that's the format you're using:

- http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=DWARF_FAQ
- http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html

Note that you can put the debugging data in whatever format you like when you compile the program, or leave it out entirely.  STABS and DWARF are common on Linux.  However, just because the executable or library isn't stripped doesn't mean that the debugging data is there.

Comment: How does gdb know when the stop printing output when you ask it to show the disassembly of a function then?  It appears that it can do that correctly even without debug data. Perhaps it's just searching for a particular (platform-specific) opcode (eg, retq on x86-64)?

Comment: I don't believe this is true. First of all, a function can `ret` from many different places; finding the last `ret` must be as hard as solving the halting problem (i.e. impossible). To link together executables the linker *must* know how large each function is (approximated to some alignment constraints) in order to build binary objects that aren't enormous.

Comment: @Conrad: The static linker needs the object size.  This information is not required by the dynamic linker.

Comment: @Dietrich: At some point the static linker must be invoked to link object files into dlls or shared objects.

Comment: @Conrad: My point is that when the program is executed, the static linker had already been run long ago and the information is gone.

Comment: @Dietrich: Hence, my point about getting the information from the object file rather than waiting until runtime to try and find it.

Answer (score 1):

It' possible to get the start address, but difficult to get the end address, for a function.  GTK does something similar to what you ask with dynamic Glade bindings.

To do this yourself, you compile your application as a dynamically-loaded image (like a shared library) using libtool, and set the image to have exported names using the libtool `-export-dynamic` option.

For more information [see this link to Libtool documentation.](http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/libtool-2.1a/libtool_9.html)

The link command to use is:

`libtool gcc -export-dynamic -o program main.o`

Once you have compiled with the `-export-dynamic` switch required, you may call `dlopen()` to dynamically open your executable image as a dynamic library, and `dlsym()` to obtain the address of specific symbols.